# how to use php in asterisk voip server

Tags: php, ubuntu, cgi, asterisk, voip

I completely set up asterisk server.In that server i completely successful to make call b/w two user through soft phone.

For make call first  i register account and dial plan  in two file namely 
sip.conf and extensions.conf respectively.

I need to know how i can interact with php script so i make dynamic.
I am using Ubuntu Os pl z help me .

pl z share some Idea and links that help me to understand how to make VoIP
API

I tried some code like that but these are completely shows error
I setup php server before asterisk server which is located in directory
/opt/lampp/htdocs/

and asterisk server is install in directory /usr/src/
pl z tell me in which directory i need to write my php code.and is the is any need to step php with asterisk.

```
 #!/usr/bin/php

<?php
/*
This script answers the call and prompts for an extension, provided your caller ID is approved.
When it receives 4 digits it will read them back to you and hang up.
*/
$debug_mode = false; //debug mode writes extra data to the log file below whenever an AGI command is executed
$log_file = '/tmp/agitest.log'; //log file to use in debug mode
$allowed_ext = array('1234', '0'); //who's allowed to access this script

//get the AGI variables; we will check caller id
$agivars = array();
while (!feof(STDIN)) {
    $agivar = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    if ($agivar === '') {
        break;
    }
    else {
        $agivar = explode(':', $agivar);
        $agivars[$agivar[0]] = trim($agivar[1]);
    }
}
foreach($agivars as $k=>$v) {
    log_agi("Got $k=$v");
}
extract($agivars);

//hangup if it's not an allowed extension
if (!empty($allowed_ext)) {
    if (!in_array($agi_callerid, $allowed_ext)) {
        log_agi("Call rejected from $agi_calleridname <$agi_callerid>");
        execute_agi('STREAM FILE goodbye ""');
        execute_agi('HANGUP');
        exit;
    }
}

//ask for an extension
$ext = '';
$result = execute_agi('STREAM FILE please-enter-the "0123456789"');
if ($result['result'] == 0) {
    $result = execute_agi('STREAM FILE users "0123456789"');
    if ($result['result'] == 0) {
        //they haven't entered anything yet
        $result = execute_agi("GET DATA extension 5000 4");
        if ($result['result'] > 0) {
            $ext = $result['result'];
        }
    }
    else {
        $ext = chr($result['result']);
    }
}
else {
    $ext = chr($result['result']);
}

//we haven't got 4 digits yet
if (strlen($ext) < 4) {
    //still no input after GET DATA timeout
    if (empty($ext)) {
        execute_agi('STREAM FILE please-enter-the ""');
        execute_agi('STREAM FILE users ""');
        execute_agi('STREAM FILE extension ""');
    }
    //we got a single digit during playback of 'please enter the' or 'users'
    while (strlen($ext) < 4) {
        $result = execute_agi('WAIT FOR DIGIT -1');
        //look for digits only
        if ($result['result'] >= 48 && $result['result'] <= 57) {
            $ext .= chr($result['result']);
        }
        //ignore * or # (or a, b, c, d)
        else {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
log_agi("Got extension $ext");

//say back the extension; at this point you could certainly do something more productive but that is left to you
execute_agi('STREAM FILE you-entered ""');
execute_agi("SAY DIGITS $ext \"\"");
execute_agi('STREAM FILE goodbye ""');
execute_agi('HANGUP');
exit;

function execute_agi($command) {
    global $debug_mode, $log_file;

    fwrite(STDOUT, "$command\n");
    fflush(STDOUT);
    $result = trim(fgets(STDIN));
    $ret = array('code'=> -1, 'result'=> -1, 'timeout'=> false, 'data'=> '');
    if (preg_match("/^([0-9]{1,3}) (.*)/", $result, $matches)) {
        $ret['code'] = $matches[1];
        $ret['result'] = 0;
        if (preg_match('/^result=([0-9a-zA-Z]*)\s?(?:\(?(.*?)\)?)?$/', $matches[2], $match))  {
            $ret['result'] = $match[1];
            $ret['timeout'] = ($match[2] === 'timeout') ? true : false;
            $ret['data'] = $match[2];
        }
    }
    if ($debug_mode && !empty($logfile)) {
        $fh = fopen($logfile, 'a');
        if ($fh !== false) {
            $res = $ret['result'] . (empty($ret['data']) ? '' : " / $ret[data]");
            fwrite($fh, "-------\n>> $command\n<< $result\n<<     parsed $res\n");
            fclose($fh);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}

function log_agi($entry, $level = 1) {
    if (!is_numeric($level)) {
        $level = 1;
    }
    $result = execute_agi("VERBOSE \"$entry\" $level");
}
?>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you take a few minutes and read the following links and grab the following software:

http://phpagi.sourceforge.net/

http://marcelog.github.io/PAGI/

http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-CHP-9-SECT-3.html

http://www.robpeck.com/2007/07/agi-php-using-php-to-route-phone-calls/

I also suggest you start -much- smaller.

Create a very simple script there and verify you can make -any- AGI run properly.  Then, build upwards in complexity.

I personally put symlinks to all my AGI code in `/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/` ; that is where Asterisk looks for it's AGI files by default.

Also, be sure your AGI scripts have the correct ownership and permissions, particularly since this one you have needs to be able to write a log file.

As well, ensure that the SELinux context is properly set for the script so that it isn't being execution-blocked.

Comment: thanks sir,  i now the Apache Server  Location is htdocs or www than how i write the code in  this directory /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/ plz help me how to use Apache server for this directory . either i need to install another Apache server For this if yes than how

Comment: You don't need Apache at all for use with Asterisk.  It's an entirely different application stack that has nothing to do with telephony.

As far as how to write code in `/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/` ... I just write my code locally, and then SCP it to my Asterisk server to test.

Comment: As explained by MichelV69 apache is not any way related to asterisk. phpagi is used to develop back end asterisk application and you have to put  those php files in /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/ and have to include that php script in dialplan through AGI()